# What is the significance of this red light on the Bitmain S9 board?

Tags: mining-hardware, antminer

How can I fix this issue? Is it fixable?

[image: S9 board red light]

Answer (score 1):

What are you seeing on your Antminer Status page? Is two of your boards showing 0 under the GH/S(RT) column?

Because I believe the absence of the light indicates an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ant s9 has 3 arithmetic boards in total, normally each arithmetic board is green light, red light means this arithmetic board is faulty.